# Array only adding one item on parse server

Tags: android, parse-server

Array only adding one item on parse server. Why this is happening? And when I wanted to delete that one item it is not deleting as well.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("arrayName")==null)
    {
        List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("arrayName",emptyList);
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
    }

    ParseUser.logInInBackground("anas", "anas", new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (e==null)
            {        
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("arrayName").add("robert");
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();                   
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I am actually facing the same issue at the moment. Would appreciate if you could share the answer to that if you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are checking 
`(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("khudaka")==null)` and after finding that "Khudaka" column is null you are trying to store an emptyList ? (it's already null) It doesn't make any sense my friend.

It will be better if you do `(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("khudaka")!=null)` and then do your delete operation.

And a suggestion, use ParseLogin code before doing any other operation for  ParseCurrentUser.